# Subwoofer hums when no audio source is connected

Tags: audio, grounding, speakers, socket, hum

The hum stops as soon as an audio source is connected or any metal part of the subwoofer is connected to the ground of a socket.

Does anyone have any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Would you be able to recognize whether the hum is related to the line frequency? My guess would be you have interference from you power lines or power supply.

Comment: Impossible to say without details. Does it have a grounded mains inlet, and is it connected to grounded mains socket?

Comment: Thanks for the answers! Unfortunately I am not an electrical specialist. The subwoofer hums at 60hz. It is connected to the socket with a 2-pin plug. The louder I switch the subwoofer the louder the hum.

Comment: Fairly common. You could probably add a 10k resistor between each signal and ground to get rid of it. Easiest is to just leave a source connected.

Comment: Bad cap. Inside . Open it

Comment: I have already removed the two large capacitors of the power supply and measured their capacity. (Unfortunately) I could not find any fault and the rest of the capacitors all look fine at first glance. Here are pictures of the components of the device. (https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=15fpuDlGdh94Cyr6GPTyjD28C6P85MKBd) Which capacitors could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Although it is only an educated guess, my guess would be that you are picking up interference from your power lines and/or power supply. If the hum is low, that is likely the cause. If you can verify that the hum has a frequency that is either the same as, or a multiple of the line frequency in your country, then it is almost certain that is the source.

Why are you picking up such interference? There are a number of causes, many of which can be solved by proper grounding. [In some cases, connecting a component to ground may *increase* hum, by creating ground loops that act like big induction coils, so adding a connection to ground is not always the solution].

One source of hum is from power supplies, especially if the device is old and or poorly made.

If grounding your device eliminates the hum, then even if you cannot pinpoint the source, you might want to just ground the device and be done with it.

You mention that the device is connected to the wall outlet with a two-prong plug. Is that because the wall outlet has only two prongs (i.e. it is not grounded) or because the device only came with two prongs?

If you are using a "cheater" adapter to plug a three-pronged cord into a 2 pronged outlet, then the device probably *needs* a ground to work properly (without hum), and you should look into the possibility of updating your wiring to include grounding. I understand that in some countries, wiring buildings without grounding is general practice. In the US it is not, and only older buildings lack grounded outlets.

Comment: The device came with a 2 pin connector. I have disassembled the subwoofer a few days ago to check the components for obvious defects. It is important to note that the subwoofer is a few years old. On which components could such inteferences occur? Here are pictures of the components of the device. (https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=15fpuDlGdh94Cyr6GPTyjD28C6P85MKBd) I will assemble the subwoofer in the meantime and see if the problem occurs at all sockets.

Comment: Do you have an idea which component could be broken? I have already tested the capacity of the two large capacitors and could not find any error.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that *anything* is broken? This sounds like it could be normal.

If you have a pair of wires that are only connected to something on one end, then that pair of wires is an antenna. An antenna will pick up whatever electromagnetic waves hit it, and the device which is connected to the antenna will see a small AC voltage as a result. In most buildings, the largest source of audio-frequency electromagnetic waves is the mains wiring. So, as long as there's nothing plugged into your subwoofer, it's always going to see a small voltage at 50 or 60 Hz, and the subwoofer probably isn't able to tell the difference between that voltage and a "real" audio signal.

The most straightforward solution to this "problem" is to simply not turn the subwoofer on while there's no device connected to the input. Is there some reason why you can't do this?